Неразрывный пробел (%C2%A0) у значения id в url
Есть сущность
@Entity
    @Table (name = "name")
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Work {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

        @Column (name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column (name = "designation", columnDefinition = "text")
        private String designation;

        @Column (name = "notes")
        private String notes;

        @Column (name = "address")
        private String address;

        @Column (name = "qty")
        private int qty;

        @Column (name = "storage")
        private String storage;

    }

При переходе по ссылке на странице "work"
<a href="/work/${work.id}" class="work-link">
Контроллер принимает id и перенаправляет на страницу infowork
  @GetMapping("/work/{id}")
public String infoWork (@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("works", editWorkServices.getWorkById(id));
    return "infowork";
}

url формирует id в виде строки с пробелом и как только id переваливает за 999 url получается следующей: http://localhost:2024/work/1%C2%A0053, в результате получаю "Whitelabel Error Page"
 Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 19 15:46:14 MSK 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "1 053"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "1 053"
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:224)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 053"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:711)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1163)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:206)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:860)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:294)
    ... 48 more

Пробовал и так:
 @GetMapping("/work/{id}")
public String infoWork (@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    Long workId = Long.parseLong(id.replace(" ", ""));
    model.addAttribute("works", editWorkServices.getWorkById(workId));
    return "infowork";
}

и так:
    @GetMapping("/work/{id}")
public String infoWork (@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    id = id.trim().replace("\\s+", "");
    Long workId = Long.parseLong(id);
    model.addAttribute("works", editWorkServices.getWorkById(workId));
    return "infowork";
}

Как испавить данную проблему?

При помощи чего вы выводите HTML-ссылки <a href="/work/${work.id}", какой-то фреймворк используется или обычный JSP?  Следует также проверить настройки локали, которые могут отвечать за вывод "больших" чисел и вставлять ненужные разделители для тысяч.

Фреймворк Spring Boot. А как проверить локальные настройки, куда нужно смотреть?

Шаблонизатор - Apache FreeMarke
